# How set 2D array to radio button?

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, radio-button

```
    String[][] choices = {
           {
                   "A",
                   "c",
                   "A"
           },
           {
                   "A",
                   "c",
                   "A"
           },
           {
                   "A",
                   "c",
                   "A"
           },
           {
                   "A",
                   "c",
                   "A"
           },
           {
                   "A",
                   "c",
                   "A"
           },
           {
                   "A",
                   "c",
                   "A"
           },
           {
                   "A",
                   "c",
                   "A"
           },
           {
                   "A",
                   "c",
                   "A"
           },
           {
                   "A",
                   "c",
                   "A"
           },
           {
                   "A",
                   "c",
                   "A"
           }
   };
```

I have a Two dimensional array with 10 rows and 3 columns.
how i can set each row ad radio button text.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_CHOICES-1; i++){
      buttons[i].setText(choices[currentQuestNum - 1][i]);
      }
//buttons[] array of radio button

//NUM_OF_CHOICES = 11
```

this is what i tried but it shows `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: length=3; index=3` in logcat.

How can i solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  String[] subArray = choices[currentQuestNum-1];
   for(int j=0;j<subArray.length;j++)
   {
      String item=subArray[j];
      buttons[j].setText(item);
   }
```

this is how i got the solution for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Also double check your buttons array and make sure you are adding same number of buttons as the number of rows.

```
for(int i=0;i < radioButtonsArray.length ;i++){  
    for(int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++){
         buttons[i].setText(choices[i][j]);
      }
}
```

Comment: do you have the same number of radio buttons as your objects in array?

Comment: probably you need to log your array lengths as well, think there is a problem with size of either radio buttons array or your dataset

Comment: i have 4 radio buttons and array column of 3... when i set values to radio button only the first three have values and the fourth one is a fake.`String[] subArray = choices[currentQuestNum-1];
   for(int j=0;j<subArray.length;j++)
   {
      String item=subArray[j];
      buttons[j].setText(item);
   }`

Comment: @AllwinJohnson I just updated the answer, have a look at that.
Actually what was happening previously was you were trying to get index[3] from radio buttons array, which actually had maximum index 2 because it had 3 items in it. And your upper loop was traversing your dataset array size which was 10. Hope this helps

Comment: got the solution by added a sub array. the above code i pasted is the soluthion

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two loops instead of one as such your correspondence array have three value in it and you're using I which is I guess size of choice array so its obvious to give that error.

Use -

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < YOUR_ARRAY[i].size; j++) {
       button[i].setText(YOUR_ARRAY[i][j]);
   }
}
```

Comment: it's not the solution for me.. u missing a bracket for setText();